# Is there any book like the "Stick and Rudder" about the helicopter?

Tags: flight-controls, books

I have read the *Stick and Rudder*, that's really a classic book. Now I want to study the flight theory about helicopters, is there any book like this?

Comment: Have you read the FAA's [Helicopter Flying Handbook](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/helicopter_flying_handbook/)?

Comment: I downloaded it, but it isn't the kind of book I wanna.I need a simply and humorous book without too many equalitions

Answer (score 2):

There's a book called "Cyclic and Collective" by Shawn Coyle. It's a good book, although it is a little bit more detailed than something like "Stick and Rudder". There's a lot of good stuff in there, though.